# python self keyword in a list

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am reading a tutorial about keras and came a cross this class that is  inherited by an other class.

```
  class LearningRateDecay:
  def plot(self, epochs, title="Learning Rate Schedule"):
    lrs = [self(i) for i in epochs]     
    plt.style.use("ggplot")
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(epochs, lrs)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel("Epoch #")
    plt.ylabel("Learning Rate")
```

in which epochs is defined like this :

```
    N = 100
    epochs = np.arange(0, N)
```

and is passed to plot function like this :

```
    a = LearningRateDecay
    a.plot(epochs,"Learning Rate Schedule")
```

I cant understand what is **self(i)** meaning? is this about accessing to self elements or some thing else?
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self(i)` refers to calling an object i.e. using their `__call__` method.

For example, consider this class:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __call__(self, arg):
        print(arg)
    def method(self):
        self('test')

a = MyClass()
a.method()  # Prints 'test'
a('other')  # Prints 'other'
```

In your example, this class probably have some defined behavior associated with `__call__` (it can also be inherited from an upper object). Refer to the class documentation to learn about it.

Comment: Yes.I got it.Thank you @Arthur Havlicek